# Obtaining map of all public space of France

Tags: data-request, geospatial, france

If possible through shapefile format (GIS), I'd like to get a map of all over Metropolitan France showing public space, id est public woodlands, public parks, roads, public lands, etc, owned by the State or by local authorities.

Comment: openstreetmap.org is a good starting point for things like this